# What is the purpose of the Publication Types: E-mail, Mobile, and Unspecified?

Tags: 2013-sp1, publication

While creating a Publication, we have below options for the **Publication Type**:

[image]:

So far, I have used **Web** and **Content** type Publications and to some extent I understand their purpose.

Can you please provide examples where and when the other types: [ **E-Mail**, **Mobile** and **Unspecified** ] need to be used?

In my project I can see many Publications which are for a Mobile website but they are all set as **Web** (060 level) and **Content** (040)? Should I set both the 060 and 040 Publications type to **Mobile**?

Are there any special content types/Component/Pages/Schema to be created when a Publication is of type **Mobile**?

Also, in which case should a Publication Type be **Unspecified**? Will Tridion automatically detect the correct type of a Publication?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, the Publication Type doesn't have much predefined meaning for the system itself (*); it is mainly intended to help users distinguish different purposes.

Note that the list of available Publication Types is customizable (in `Tridion.ContentManager.config`.

In a typical BluePrint, you will find Publications which merely acts as Repositories and are not intended for publishing (Publication Type `Undefined` or `Content`) and Publications representing Websites (Publication Type `Web` or `Mobile`).

Publication Type `Mobile` is a bit dubious, because nowadays responsive design is often used to make website accessible to mobile too. But, again, the system doesn't care which Publication Type you use for a Site Publication.

(*) Note that the SDL Web 8 Site Wizard does use Publication Type to locate *Site Types* and Content Publications.

Answer (score 3):

One possible use of these Publication types is in those scenario where number of publications in the system are big and it is difficult to navigate/find publications - there you can use these publication types to filter publications in CME as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please find below example code and update your customized publication Type in Tridion.ContentManager.config file and restart services.

```
 \tridion\config\Tridion.ContentManager.config




<publicationTypes>
      <!-- 
      Constraints: 
          1) id and name attribute is unique. 
          2) id > 1024. Numbers below 1024 are reserved.
          3) titleResource is optional. if titleResource is not provided then the value specified in name will be used as PublicationType.Title
      -->
      <add id="1" name="Content" titleResource="lblContentPublicationType" />
      <add id="2" name="Web" titleResource="lblWebPublicationType" />
      <add id="4" name="Mobile" titleResource="lblMobilePublicationType" />
      <add id="5" name="SiteType" titleResource="lblSiteTypePublicationType" />
    </publicationTypes>
```

Comment: I don't see "below example code"